# Fitting a fully parametric proportional hazard model with time-varying covariates in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I need to fit a parametric PH model (so, not a Cox model) with time-varying covariates. Can we do that in R? I heard the survreg function cannot handle time-varying covariates. I've looked in vain for packages that could deal with that.

Comment: Would this package help: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/joineR/index.html

Comment: you could transform your data and fit a glm or gam with `family = poisson` (see http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s4.html)

Comment: Terry Therneau, the (an?) author of the survival package has not placed this as a priority (see: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/161027.html). This works fine in the Stata parametric survival analysis packages, if you have access to that. SAS does not implement counting process style data in parametric survival models at this time, to my knowledge.  EDIT: Terry T. has been responsive to emails in the past, so perhaps you could submit a request with a reasonable example in which this model is needed - this is an approach that would be helpful to many, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

As @adibender writes, you can easily estimate a model with a constant baseline with the `poisson` family with a log time `offset` with `glm`. Here is an example

```
> # Input parameters
> n <- 100         # Number of individuals
> t_max <- 5       # max number of period per individual
> beta <- c(-1, 1) # true coefficient
> 
> # Simulate data
> set.seed(47261114)
> sim_dat <- replicate(
+   n, 
+   {
+     out <- data.frame(
+       tstart = rep(NA_integer_, t_max), 
+       tstop  = rep(NA_integer_, t_max),
+       event  = rep(NA, t_max),
+       x      = rnorm(t_max))
+     
+     for(i in 1:t_max){
+       rate     <- exp(beta %*% c(1, out$x[i]))
+       tstop <- min(rexp(1, rate), 1)
+       out[i, ] <- list(i - 1, i - (1 - tstop),  tstop < 1, out$x[i])
+       if(out$event[i])
+         break
+     }
+     out[!is.na(out$tstart), ]
+   }, simplify = FALSE)
> 
> sim_dat <- do.call(rbind, sim_dat)
> head(sim_dat) # show final data
  tstart     tstop event          x
1      0 0.3018182  TRUE  0.7095841
2      0 0.6724803  TRUE  1.5152877
3      0 1.0000000 FALSE  0.1036868
4      1 2.0000000 FALSE -0.5214508
5      2 2.4831577  TRUE  1.0101403
6      0 1.0000000 FALSE  0.1437594
> 
> # Fit with glm
> glm(event ~ x + offset(log(tstop - tstart)), sim_dat, family = poisson())

Call:  glm(formula = event ~ x + offset(log(tstop - tstart)), family = poisson(), 
    data = sim_dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.9053       0.9714  

Degrees of Freedom: 248 Total (i.e. Null);  247 Residual
Null Deviance:      382.5 
Residual Deviance: 306.4    AIC: 498.4
```

For other distribution, it seems like the [`flexsurv`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/) package may do. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208306/81865).